# django how to format date to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

django how to format date to DD/MM/YYYY in this case :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: A model is not about how to *format* things. A model is about storing things. So basically a model has no "format" (or at least not one to the "outside world"). You format it in templates, forms, etc.

Comment: so what you can suggest as solution, i just shared my case

Comment: as said, you specify the format in the template (or in the settings that are used by the template), and in the forms (although these also take the settings as default format).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Comment: please follow the format for asking a question. on a side note, read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/) if you'd like to read more about formatting dates(or anything else) in the database, specifically the section on date time field and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for dates in python

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Model` is not about how you present data to the customer, it is about how you store data in the database.

If you present data to the user, it depends on the settings that are active. If for example [**`USE_L10N`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_L10N) is active, it will try to determine the locale of the user, and based on that format the date. This means that a German user will see a different date format than an American user for example.

If `USE_L10N` is set to `False`, the form field with use the first item in the [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS). By default this is:

> ```
> [
>     '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
>     '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
>     '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
>     '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
>     '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006' ]
> ```

so it will first format the year, month and then date, so `2020-08-28` for example. You thus can specify a different element (first) to change this for all `Form`s that have [**`DateField`** fields <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#datefield).

If you want to specify a one-off field, you can use the [**`format=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput.format) of the `DateInput` widget for example:

```
from django import forms

class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m%Y'))

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then you should also include the format in the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` setting, and better with a higher priority than "overlapping" formats like `%m/%d/%Y` and `%m/%d/%y`, to ensure that the value can also be parsed.

You can also provide a one-off list of input formats in the form field by specifying a [**`input_formats=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields./#django.forms.DateField.input_formats).

Comment: it works on fields, but for html, how i can proceed ? in case <td>{{ invoice.date }}</td> and also in case of <td>date</td>

Comment: @youssefmohamed: by specifying the `DATE_FORMAT` setting https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-format or with the `|date` filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) for one-off's, so `{{ invoice.date|date:'Y-m-d' }}`.

Comment: back to field, when i update my field it shows dd/mm/yy, i click on update then next page it becomes mm/dd/yy ! i want only one format dd/mm/yyyy. thanks